# Managing machine AD accounts for scaled roles in a cloud service

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

We domain-join the Virtual Machines associated with our Cloud Service roles.  Of course, the process of joining the domain forces a reboot.  And, when scaling up, this is fine.  However, when scaling-down we want to automatically remove the machines AD Account from the domain.  I don't see a way to execute a "before or after" event in Azure auto-scaling.  The current prescription is to override the roles OnStop event.  However, there is no way to tell if it is a simple reboot or an actual deallocation.  Of course, I can hack-in a process, myself.

However, is anyone else out there doing this? How do you accomplish this elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated**
To rephrase the question... what is the best way to manage machine identities when you have PaaS based role instances that are being domain joined to an IaaS domain controller.

IMHO, there are two approaches that can be taken: a passive approach where an inventory of the PaaS role instances is taken and then changes applied to the DC; and an active approach where on shut-down, the role instances need to actively notify the DC that they are being removed.

For the passive solution, the best option might be to have a process that periodically queries the PaaS Cloud Service topology via the "[Get Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460804.aspx)" Service Management API. The response to this operation includes a list of all the current role instances and their status.

The active solution would require placing code into the RoleEntryPoint that would actively send a status alert notification message to the DC so the role instance could be removed. For this approach, you could trap in any number of possible hooks: [RoleEnvironment.Changing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx), [RoleEnvironment.Changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changed.aspx), [RoleEnvironment.Stopping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.stopping.aspx), [RoleEnvironment.OnStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstop.aspx).

The challenge with either method will be differentiating the deprovisioning of a role instance from when one is simply being rebooted (say for a guest OS update).

Comment: Is this because when you provision VMs they use dynamic names and you're just trying to clean things up? Yes!

Comment: Ah, simply put then stop dynamically allocating and destroying them unless you absolutely have to. Keeping machines around in a stopped state can often be much more efficient, both in cost, and start up time.

Comment: Thanks for the help: I am new to this, but it "seems" like you are talking about IaaS. Please keep in mind...we are using "Web Roles" in a Cloud Service...so scaling is accomplished automagically. I have no idea "how" to tell Azure to "create, activate & hold" web role instances separately (your initial worker is out there...that's it). And...these web roles need to use our Virtual Network for Windows Authentication (in order to work). We do not have a separate Identity server available...so we cant simply authenticate programmatically (yet).

Comment: Your original question said... "Virtual Machines", so my apologies if I mistook this for being IaaS based. That said, the instances as they scale up and down are fairly predictably named. So I'm not certain you need to expend much effort in removing older names. However, I haven't personally validated this, so I'm only about 60% certain. :) To fix the underlying issue, might I suggest that you simply have the AD server periodically hit the Management API to retrieve a list of instances, and then act accordingly, cleaning up unused machine names.

Comment: So, the "API Management Service" is the best way to query & manage Cloud Service VM's?  If so, could you take a moment to restructure your answer (along with "some" details & links) on how?  This way, I can review and mark your answer as correct.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: From outside of the cloud service, I feel the Management API is the best approach.